# resetting values in $_POST so that forms is not sticky

Tags: php

I'm reading code where in the module handling user registration I've found the following:

```
// Reset values so form is not sticky
$_POST = array();
```

I don't understand why it is there and how resetting values could make the form not sticky. Any ideas?

Comment: What is a sticky form?

Comment: A form that attracts bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you are reading populates the form fields (input, select etc.) from data within the $_POST array, then by assigning it to a new blank `array()` there will be no value for any of the fields and population will not occur and the value will not be "sticky" upon reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, elsewhere in the program is some code that sets the `value` attributes of form controls to use the values from `$_POST`. Wiping those values out prevents that code from populating the fields with the previously submitted data.